# Android TabLayout

Tags: android

Как можно расположить одновременно 3-4 вкладки на экране, но чтобы при выборе элемента, который ближе к границе экрана, Toolbar пролистывался?

**Текущие положение**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно сделать что-то подобное как в Playmarkete
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Одновременно находится 3.5 элемента, остальные появляются/скрываются по мере выбора соседних элементов от выбранного

Answer (score 3):

Вам надо [указать](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31363206/3212712) что tab-ы скролятся через `app:tabMode="scrollable"`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:tabMode="scrollable" />
```

Comment: Спасибо большое